# Ping pelo cmd em arquivo bat

Tags: cmd, ping

[image: TESTANDO PING POR ARQUIVO.bat]

Opa, alguem sabe o por que de isso acontecer? quando eu testo p ping pelo cmd funciona, porem quando eu testo por um arquivo.bat ele fica consultando sem parar, infinitamente e trava... alguem pode me ajudar

Comment: Adicione como está passando o comando no seu arquivo bat.

Answer (score 1):

Via arquivo .bat, se você apenas passar `ping [host]`, ele vai executar infinitamente mesmo. Você precisa passar o parâmetro `-n` e o número de vezes que quer executar o ping.

Por exemplo, o comando abaixo salvo num bat vai "pingar" o google ´por 6 vezes e encerrar:

```
ping -n 6 www.google.com.br
```

Na [documentação](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ff961503(v=ws.10).aspx) há uma lista de parâmetros, caso queira incrementar o comando.